# Refresh BindingSource correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

I have a master-detail grid view on windows forms. I a very simple Repository (repo in code) that queries the database to get back DataTables.

At first I load the Data and define a relation like u see in the LoadData() method. Next, After I edit my Master table I want to refresh the view datasource. That's the unimplemented RefreshData(); method. If I'm refreshing after Edit I need the bindingsource not to lose the "current" row.

Here is the code:

```
    public void LoadData() 
    {
        //define the Bindingsource and 2 Datatables.

        binder = new BindingSource();
        tbTaxPayers = repo.GetTaxPayersDataTable(-1);
        tbLinkedOrganizations = repo.GetTaxPayersLinkedOrganizations();

        //create a dataset to define the relation so that the view can pick it up
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(tbTaxPayers);
        ds.Tables.Add(tbLinkedOrganizations);
        ds.Relations.Add("LinkedOrganizations", tbTaxPayers.Columns["CLI_ID"], tbLinkedOrganizations.Columns["LCC_CLI_ID_PARENT"]);

        //set datasource to the main table.
        binder.DataSource = tbTaxPayers;
        view.LoadData(binder);
    }


    public void RefreshData()
    {
       // how to refresh without overhead ? and without losing focus if I just edit ?
    }
```

EDIT:

By doing the next code it works but I have to create a new DataSet with every refresh. And it smells to me cause it almost a duplicate of my LoadData() method.

```
public void RefreshData()
    {
        tbTaxPayers = repo.GetTaxPayersDataTable(-1);
        tbLinkedOrganizations = repo.GetTaxPayersLinkedOrganizations();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(tbTaxPayers);
        ds.Tables.Add(tbLinkedOrganizations);
        ds.Relations.Add("LinkedOrganizations", tbTaxPayers.Columns["CLI_ID"], tbLinkedOrganizations.Columns["LCC_CLI_ID_PARENT"]);
        binder.DataSource = tbTaxPayers;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you refreshing your data ?  Is it changing because you edited some data ?

Comment: Can't you just update the object the data source is linked to which the user changed ? Rather than loading the data again.

Comment: I don't understand. you mean just to pass the "delta" of what operations the user did back to the top level form which has a read-only list of the master data ?